# Page break on horizontal layout table

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a dynamically generated horizontal table which renders this sample html...

```
<div>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                ....(repeated till 30 cells)
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="body1">
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                ....(repeated till 30 cells)
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                ....(repeated till 30 cells)
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                ....(repeated till 30 cells)
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody id="body2">
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                ....(repeated till 30 cells)
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                ....(repeated till 30 cells)
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

My problem is when I try to print in landscape mode, it fits into one page by shrinking content which is unreadable. Is there a way I can avoid it by introducing page break after 20 cells either by using jQuery/css or by any other means?
I'm looking for something like this

first page...

```
<table>
    <tr>
        | td1 | td2 |...| td20 | 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        | td1 | td2 |...| td20 | 
    </tr>
</table>
```

second page...

```
<tr>
    | td21 | td22 |...| td30 | 
</tr>
<tr>
    | td21 | td22 |...| td30 | 
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `page-break`:

CSS

```
table { 
  display:block;
  page-break-inside:auto 
}

tr { 
  page-break-inside:avoid; 
  page-break-after:auto; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always do it with CSS property page-break-inside. Needs some design or can be set to auto also.

For more info visit following:

[w3schools: page break property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pagebi.asp)

[css tricks: page break property & examples](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/page-break/)

```
table { 
  page-break-inside:auto 
}

tr { 
  page-break-inside:avoid; 
  page-break-after:auto; 
}
```